# .NET - How to generate random numbers in a range with a certain step size?

Tags: vb.net, random, range

I'd like to generate random numbers in a range (say between 0 and 1) - but with a certain step size (say 0.05).
There's a [python function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/number_randrange.htm) that does exactly that:

```
random.randrange ( [start,] stop [,step] )
```

So my problem is not how to generate random numbers in a range - instead I need a way to do this with a certain **step size**.
How can this be done in .NET?

Comment: You should be able to work it out with some maths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could generate a random integer between 0 and 20 and divide the result by 20

```
Dim rnd = New Random()
Dim nextValue = rnd.Next(21) / 20
```

This will give you a random number between 0 and 1 (inclusive) in 0.05 increments

Comment: @bluebox what if you have a range if you want to start at like 95

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
  Dim objRandom As New System.Random
  Label1.Text = Math.Round(objRandom.NextDouble() * 2, 1) / 2
```

So you create a random double and you round it to one digit (example: 0.8).
Then you divided it with 2 and you get what you want